# Is it possible to add new location to Google Map API's using Data layer

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I am very new to Google Map API's. I am reading through their documentation and trying to find out few things:

1. Is it possible to add custom location to Google Map API's?

So the scenario would be: user want's to add new location to map. Something like `contribute` that already exist on Google Maps.

I saw in documentation that there is no `POST method` for maps so I guess `Contribute` option is not available through their API's.

Reading further I have come to part Data layer.

2. Is it possible to add some layer above google maps where is possible to allow users to add and remove locations as they want and save that data to custom database?

Is something that Google Map Data layer can be used for?

Or what could be used to achieve custom location adding to map?

I am trying to do this using Java and Spring Boot, so if anyone had any experience with it please let me know.

Any advice really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maps allows you to show the user locations on the map via 'markers'. Markers have infowindows.
If you want to handle these locations via a database. Then you may want to create a class object that you can map to.

Comment: I am aware of markers, but how can I add custom location? Do I need to put somekind of layer above google maps?

Comment: What do you mean by 'custom location'?

Comment: Do you know how `contribute` works on Google Maps? So it would be same. For example you are walking and you find a place you would recommend and you want to add it to map... that would be adding a custom location

Comment: Oh! You want to contribute to Google Maps, via the Google Maps API. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I read that it was deprecated and the removed. But I am wondering is there some layer that I can add on top of google maps and add it and remove there?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure. I'm going to delete my answer. But you may want to clarify your question for the next person.